# Marque Scrolling text in UILabel

Tags: iphone

I want to set the text in Scroll label at center, can any one help me regarding this

Comment: you need to look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code I think this will work for you.

```
UILabel *compete_Label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 60, 20)];
[compete_Label setText:@"Compete"];
compete_Label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[compete_Label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
compete_Label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[scrollviewobject addSubview:compete_Label];
```

Comment: vishiphone, my problem is i have 2 labels on a UIView... and i wanna scroll the text on one label that is coming from server side...if that text is large,it is scrolling and no problem there.... if that text is small, i wanna set that text at center.... can u please help me....?

Comment: then you can set the property for label set alignment only.or other thing you always start label from middle only in particular postion using frame size .

Comment: then use center property and set label to particular position

Comment: use settextallignment if it is not working or you are not getting that property then I think you are wrong with create label.

Comment: ok if it will hwlp for you then mark my answer its helpful for other one and also up the my ans arrow thanks.

Comment: you also tap on arrow for up side(+1).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple:

```
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: i tried like this...but in my app, my scroll label wont have such type of property....

Comment: @Rupa Are you using a UITextField?, that one has the same property as well.

Comment: So are you have one label on scroll view which you want in middle right?

Comment: So You can also set the frame of label,are u have only on label right?

Comment: ok try above code you have dynamic label right?then use this code and set your label frame as your wish.

Comment: If its is work for you inform me and also pull the answer arrow up and tick the correct mark so it will help others also.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [CALayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). You can find details about several animations here.